# Is it possible to store data in google drive instead to store in firebase?

Tags: ionic4

Currently, I'm using ionic 4 and wants to store data in login user's google drive. Is it possible to store data in google drive when I logged in using Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

The answer [seems to be yes](https://hintdesk.com/2018/08/24/angular-google-drive-api-example/) but it's not a very well supported scenario.

I think the scope of what your asking is pretty much beyond what anyone could reasonably put into an answer.

If you are doing it to try to save money, and you are also new to Ionic/Angular, then I would suggest just learning it with Firebase first to get experience. That way when you get stuck you have a chance of finding somebody who has done it before or a tutorial to help.